# Safety and practicality of a sweating ritual using hot coals

Tags: biology, society, humans, trans-humanism, safety

I am imagining rituals for a society that I am developing.  I've heard of native american sweat lodges and global sauna culture, and I am considering something similar for my Pandemonic society.

While sweat lodges and saunas often use warm wet air to create a sensation of heat, the temperatures involved are low since the humidity of the air makes sweating less effective.  I have also heard of dry saunas, where the air temperature can be higher than in a wet sauna because the dryness of the air allows sweat to evaporate quickly and provide the participants with better cooling.  I have also heard of radiant heat saunas, where the heat is applied by radiant devices such as heat lamps, rather than heated air or steam.

Now, for my Pandemonic society, I am considering a ritual where the participants are literally roasted over a bed of hot coals in order to promote sweating over a prolonged period of time.  A tray of glowing coals would be placed beneath supports upon which the participant would be suspended, so that they would be exposed to the radiant heat and warm air from the coals.  They would be turned regularly so that they weren't constantly exposing one side of their bodies to the heat.

The goal of this ritual is to promote sweating, not to be fatal or even potentially so, despite the appearance that the participants are being cooked alive.  The coals should be placed at a sufficient distance that they would not cause burns, and air circulation would be used to keep the air temperature down at a safe level.  The participants would also have constant access to hydration.

The participants in this ritual *may* be transhuman, in that they have been genetically modified to be more resistant to radiant heat burns, but they may also be normal humans.

Are there any other factors that I should consider, given that I want this ritual to *appear* dangerous or even cruel, especially to an outsider, but to actually be safe and pleasant for the participants?

Comment: Saunas are essentially dry heat. A fire is used to heat up the stones and the building prior to people entering. https://saunologia.fi/in-english/finnish-sauna-essentials-part-3/

Answer (score 6):

## The difference between sauna and cooking

Your description differs only in one element from many saunas. Many saunas are heated by hot coals themselves, the humidity controlled by adding water to the hot coals.

The difference is that you put people directly above the fire in harms way. Depending on how close they are to the coals, the air will be too warm and directly burn them, regardless of sweating. The coals also have an imperfect burn, giving off many toxic fumes that are bad for health on both long and short term. Finally sone debris like ash can float from the coals, which hold a high amount of heat that can burn the victims on contact.

This means you are either hanging them very high above the fire, mostly reducing the burn hazards and a little bit the toxicity, or you move them next to the fire, making it a more mundane sauna.

### Fume hoods

As an alternative you can shield your people from the direct effects, but still having a bit of the original idea. Use metal fume hoods. The heat is then transferred via the metal, which can even surround the person suspended in the air. As long as they don't touch the metal they should be safe from both the toxicity and the burn effects. Their sweat also doesn't touch the coals, which could have other adverse effects (fire dying, direct transfer if heat via droplets) In the end it's little more than a different way of having a sauna, but the original was much like it. Having someone suspended between hot metal surfaces is something unique as far as I know, so worth a try.

Comment: I was contemplating the use of coals, where the fire has burned down to the point where there are no visible flames, so there should be few embers.  However, I agree that adjusting the height and amount and placement of embers would be important.  I'm trying to make a ritual that requires a minimum of apparatus, and a fume hood sounds like a very large piece of apparatus indeed.  It would also reduce the perception of the ritual being dangerous, and as I've stated, the appearance of danger is important.

Comment: By the way, you've hit upon the exact effect I'm after: It is supposed to *look* like the participants are being cooked alive.  An outsider would easily get the wrong impression.

Answer (score 5):

You should also consider that the hot air raised by the hot coals will be poor in oxygen and rich in CO2 and CO.

CO in particular plays nasty trick on human biology, bonding to hemoglobin permanently rather than in a reversible way like CO2 or oxygen. This means that your devotees risk being poisoned by CO if proper precautions are not taken.

The simplest I can think of is have the air flow not cross the region where they are rolling: heat them by the side, not from the bottom.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a great problem for fire walking, but that's over a far shorter duration.

Comment: Where I come from some forms of barbecue involve digging a king size bed sized hole, filling it with coal, and roasting cattle whole over it. The CO doesn't bother you mucj, but then again you can only do it in open spaces. For closed spaces the idea in this post is a necessity if the vict... er, pious person is to survive.

Comment: @TheSquare-CubeLaw An open space wouldn't be a problem.  In fact, I envisage it taking place outdoors in carefully selected conditions, including sufficient wind, or in a specially built structure that would include mechanical ventilation.

Answer (score 2):

My thoughts on this is that it's gonna be the Infrared Radiation that's the problem here.

So, I'm a regular sauna user (Local Gym has one and after each Gym session I'll do 3x 15 minute sessions in the Sauna) - It's hot, I sweat lots - life is good. Temp wise it's about 70-75 degrees C. There was another Gym that had a 2-stage Sauna (a Hot room and a **really** hot room) - and that other one was like 90 degrees C.

In short - really hot.

However... Whilst I can sit for 15 minutes in a 70-80 degrees C room, sweating like a priest in a kindergarten - if I put my hand over the heating element where the coals are, I can't hold it there for more than a few seconds. The infrared heat coming off of them is way hotter.

I'm also thinking of time spent outside around a camp bonfire, a Safe distance from it of 3-4 metres is comfortable, but that's not *over* the fire, it's off to the side.

Potentially, you could do something like an Indirect Smoker - where it would just be smoke/steam, like American style BBQ - and with enough tweaking and context (e.g. the same apparatus being used to cook/smoke meats) that could work.

Or if you had the individual not *over* the hot coals, but off to the side, leaning into the hot coals like this:

/\    \

^Fire ^Individual.

However, with the persons' head would be closest to the fire, not ideal.

Comment: It seems that you're used to hot air saunas.  There are also IR saunas, using heat-lamps.  My idea was supposed to be a primitive IR sauna made using hot coals, that became a tradition.  Hell... they might even *really* cook their BBQ dinner alongside the sweating participants.

Comment: @MontyWild your problem is convection which means areas above the fire are MUCH hotter than the same distance to the side. If the distance can cook meat it will be lethal to humans.

Comment: being on the side is a good idea, Look at mediaeval spit boys whose job it was to turn meat on spits over fires in kitchens for the what that is like. unpleasant but survivable.